#    Better way to update feed on FB with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk

I am a novice with the Facebook API. I have read so many tutorials and I am still confused.I find that I can post to the feed with API methods like this:

```
$data = array("message" => "Hello World!");
$status = $fb->api("/me/feed", "POST", $data);
```

and that is correct, second way is using cURL, something like this:

```
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE
```

Which way is better?

Comment: just double checking that you have downloaded and place the facebook PHP SDK in your directory? I'm sure there is an example in the SDK aswell. To post on a user's wall you will require the `stream_publish` permission so you need to show the auth dialogue.

Comment: Thank @martincarlin87 for quick answer,i already do that,testing both examples and everything is ok,but for future work i need to know what is best way,or maybe better approach to do that.I dont like just copy paste,i want to learn but in this case i am very confused.

Comment: I removed some `<br/>` tags from your code samples.  If you have those `<br/>` tags in your code you can remove them.

Comment: @Lix Thx for remove,this is my first post,i will take carry in next posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a subjective question.

While using `curl` may seems good way (with more control on what's going on) I personally prefer and recommend to use [PHP-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) for obvious reasons:

- Officially supported
- Most changes to API will be transparent to you with update to SDK

Comment: I do not think that this is a subjective question.  Unless there is some specific reason NOT to use the SDK, I cant think of any reasons that manually communicating with the API would be "better" than using an official SDK.

Comment: I do agree with you on usage of Official SDK, but unless decision on what to use is based on your opinion of what is "better" it's a [subjective](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Asubjective) ;)

Comment: Thank @Lix and Juicy Scripter you give me the right answer.Respect and see you :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a valid reason not to use the facebook SDK, the first method you posted is the better one.